# Inclusive indexing in NumPy gives different dimensions from using single index

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

AFAIK NumPy colon indexing operation is inclusive for the second argument, so why am I getting different array dimensions when using single index Vs. colon indexing?

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>X = np.random.randint(1,5,(3,4))
>>>X[0,:].shape
(4,)
>>>X[0:1,:].shape # should be identical to X[0,:].shape?
(1, 4)
```

Comment: Scalar index reduces that dimension (the 3 in your example).  Slice indexing retains it.

Comment: And `X[:,0]` produces a (3,), while `X[0, 0]` a scalar (0d).  `X[[0],[0]]` a (1,1).